# AngularJS loading different views through routes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display two pages, but use a base layout. I have it somewhat working with the following:

**index.html**

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-view class="container"></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
    <h2> Hello! This is Main page </h2>
</div>
```

**list.html**

```
<div>
    <h2> This is List page </h2>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Routing Setup
function myAppRouteConfig($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.html'
    }).
    when('/list', {
        controller: ListController,
        templateUrl: 'list.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}

myApp.config(myAppRouteConfig);
```

This somewhat works when I visit index.html and list.html, but two problems:

- When I load **index.html**, bootstrap loads fine. But when I visit **list.html**, bootstrap doesn't load. In fact, looking at the html source in firebug, all the code from **index.html** isn't loaded. The container is missing, the script and css links are missing.
- How do I load an actual index page? I have my **main.html** that I want to load when a user visits the root page, but **index.html** is the base layout that contains code that persists through all other views (ie, like header and footer etc). If I modify my app.js and set the `templateUrl: 'main.html'`, it seems to still load `index.html`. Is AngularJS implicitly looking for index.html as the base template?

**EDIT:**

File structure:

```
-- server.js
-- public/
      |-- index.html
      |-- list.html
      |-- main.html
      |-- js
          |-- app.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, it turns out my AngularJS route requires `ngRoute`, which is its own module now. After including it, it started to display the correct pages.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
    }).
    when('/list', {
        controller: ListController,
        templateUrl: 'list.html'
    }).
    //if you need to use login page, add 1 more route
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

and put your `index.html` at the root directory (or any sub directory) of your web app, configure it as the default document.

> Is AngularJS implicitly looking for index.html as the base template?

There is nothing related to angular here, this is the normal behavior of loading an html page from a web server.

**Here is how it works:**

When users access your application at the root url (e.x: http://example.com) or any sub directory (http://example.com/public), the `index.html` is loaded into browser like with normal web applications, then your `app.js` is run as normal. When the routes are registered and the application is bootstrapped, angular checks the route and loads `main.html` to be inserted into the container where `ng-view` is declared.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I get a blank page when visiting root. Also, why doesn't bootstrap load for login.html? All the code from `index.html` is gone when I visit the login page. Could it be my file directory structure?

Comment: @user21398: you should have only 1 `index.html` for your whole app. If you need login page, modify the route config to add 1 more route. I'll update my answer with an example.